# How to know if the next or previous button of mat paginator is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I've battling around the logic to check if the `first` `last` `next` or `previous` button of mat-paginator is clicked, search around the bunch of sites but could not found any reasonable way.

How can I check which one of the buttons is clicked?

This is how my pagination information looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The below is the explanation of how mat-paginator is implemented in Angular applications using Angular Material data table.

**.html**

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageIndex]="pageNo"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" (page)="pageEvents($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

**.ts**

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';

@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true})
paginator: MatPaginator;

pageSize: number;
pageNo: number;

ngOnit() {
   this.pageSize = 10;
   this.pageNo = 0;
}

pageEvents(event: any) {
   console.log(event.pageIndex);
   console.log(event.pageSize);
   if(event.pageIndex > this.pageNo) {
     // Clicked on next button
   } else {
     // Clicked on previous button
   }
   // The code that you want to execute on clicking on next and previous buttons will be written here.
}
```

Comment: yes I know,
but can you help me write the conditions to know which button is clicked.
I've been trying different logics, my mind is about to explode :/

Comment: thank you so much, and how about `first` and `last` page as well, because what I was trying, was causing trouble, because of logic.
Can you please tell me a simple way to check that as well,

Comment: I've updated my question so you can check how my pagination information looks like

Answer (score 7):

mat-paginator provides function for on page change event. Add this in mat-paginator so that it triggers this function when you click next or previous button:

in .html:

```
<mat-paginator (page)="pageChanged($event)">
```

$event is a object which contains previousPageIndex, pageIndex, pageSize and length.

Add this hack:

If previousPageIndex is greater than pageIndex, that means it is previous button that is clicked. else if the previousPageIndex is less than pageIndex that means it is next button that is clicked

in .ts:

```
pageChanged(event) {
  if (event.previousPageIndex > event.pageIndex) {
     // previous button clicked
  } else {
    // next button clicked
  }
}
```

Comment: Changing the page size changes also almost everything =/

Comment: I would agree with @gleitonfranco, that this is not the correct solution, since it won't distinguish page size change.